# Unable to get data from the razor-pages form

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to pass the ListOfUserModel data to **class**(NewUser.cshtml) from the **rajor page**(NewUser.cshtml) but always getting 0 records. I am adding the records in the table and trying to pass those records to the class on click of submit button. Can anyone please help me to understand what I am doing wrong here?

**Sample HTML Page**

[image]

**NewUser.cshtml**

```
@page
@model NewUserModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "New User";
}

<h5 style="margin-left: 15px;">Request New Users</h5>

<div class="container mt-3">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <form id="request-form" method="post">
                <div class="form-group row" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2 required" for="inputWorkload">Workload</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" id="inputWorkload" placeholder="Workload" asp-for="NewUser.Workload">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="userDiv">
                    <div class="form-group row" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-2 required" for="inputName">Name</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" id="inputName" placeholder="Name" asp-for="NewUser.Name">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p aria-hidden="true" id="required-description">
                    <span class="required"> </span> Required field
                </p>
                <p id="entry-error">@Model.Error</p>

                <div class="form-group row" style="margin-bottom: 15px;width: fit-content;cursor: pointer;" onclick="AddUserRecords()">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="22" height="22" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-plus-square" viewBox="0 0 16 16" style="width: fit-content;">
                        <path d="M14 1a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v12a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h12zM2 0a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v12a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h12a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V2a2 2 0 0 0-2-2H2z" />
                        <path d="M8 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v3h3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-3v3a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-3h-3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h3v-3A.5.5 0 0 1 8 4z" />
                    </svg> Add User
                </div>
                <table class="table-bordered" style="width: 100%;" id="tableUserRecord">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                Workload
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Name
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
                <div style="float: right; padding-top: 10px;">
                    <button type="button" id="btnClearData" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="clearForm()">Clear</button>
                    <button type="submit" id="btnSubmitData" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnSubmitData").click(function () {
            SubmitData();
        });
    });

    function AddUserRecords() {
        var userRecord = "<tr><td>" + $("#inputWorkload").val() + "</td><td>" + $("#inputName").val() + "</td></tr>";
        $("#tableUserRecord").last().append(userRecord);
        $("#inputName").val("");
    }

    function SubmitData() {
        var ListOfUserModel = new Array();
        $("#tableUserRecord").find("tr:gt(0)").each(function () {
            var Workload = $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text();
            var Name = $(this).find("td:eq(1)").text();

            @*alert(Workload + " " + Name);*@

            var UserModel = {};
            UserModel.Workload = Workload;
            UserModel.Name = Name;

            ListOfUserModel.append(UserModel);
        });
    }
</script>
```

**NewUser.cshtml.cs**

```
using Tool.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace Tool.Pages
{
    public class NewUserModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public UserModel NewUser { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public List<UserModel> ListOfUserModel { get; set; }

        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
        public string? Error { get; set; }
        public void OnGet()
        {
        }

        public IActionResult OnPost(IEnumerable<UserModel> ListOfUserModel)
        {
            try
            {
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("/NewUser", new { Error = "An error occoured" });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UserModel.cs**

```
namespace Tool.Models
{
    public class UserModel
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }    
        public string? Workload { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.You use `type="submit"` button without using `e.preventDefault();` which caused do not hit `SubmitData` function.

2.Your `SubmitData` function add the json array `ListOfUserModel` but do not even use it.

3.The js Array does not contain `.append` function. You need use `.push`.

Two ways can achive your requirement:

### First way of using ajax

```
@section Scripts
{
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnSubmitData").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();             //add this....
            SubmitData();
        });
    });

    function AddUserRecords() {
        var userRecord = "<tr><td>" + $("#inputWorkload").val() + "</td><td>" + $("#inputName").val() + "</td></tr>";
        $("#tableUserRecord").last().append(userRecord);
        $("#inputName").val("");
    }

    function SubmitData() {
        var ListOfUserModel = new Array();
        $("#tableUserRecord").find("tr:gt(0)").each(function () {
            var Workload = $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text();
            var Name = $(this).find("td:eq(1)").text();
            var UserModel = {};
            UserModel.Workload = Workload;
            UserModel.Name = Name;
            ListOfUserModel.push(UserModel);      //modify here....
        });
        console.log(ListOfUserModel)

         //add ajax...
        $.ajax({
            url: "/NewUser",
            type: 'post',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
            data: JSON.stringify(ListOfUserModel),
            success: function() {
                //do your stuff after callback
            }
         })
    }
</script>
}
```

Add `[FromBody]` to OnPost:

```
public IActionResult OnPost([FromBody]IEnumerable<UserModel> ListOfUserModel)
{
    try
    {
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return RedirectToPage("/NewUser", new { Error = "An error occoured" });
    }
}
```

### The second way of using form submit

table elements cannot be posted to the backend by form submit, you need add the hidden input. Also only need `AddUserRecords` function. `SubmitData` function is useless.

```
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        var count = 0;  //add it.............
        function AddUserRecords() {
               //modify here...................
            var userRecord = "<tr><td>" + $("#inputWorkload").val() +  "<input value='" + $("#inputWorkload").val() + "' name='[" + count+"].Workload' hidden />" + "</td><td>" + $("#inputName").val() + "<input value='" + $("#inputName").val() + "' name='[" + count+"].Name' hidden />"+ "</td></tr>";  
            $("#tableUserRecord").last().append(userRecord);
            $("#inputName").val("");
            count++;                //add this.......
        }   
    </script>
}
```

Backend:

```
public IActionResult OnPost(IEnumerable<UserModel> ListOfUserModel)
{
    try
    {
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return RedirectToPage("/NewUser", new { Error = "An error occoured" });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You so much for helping with the issue that too with proper explanation. I tried the Ajax way and it worked successfully...